# LINQ to order by two columns

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I want to order by two columns using LINQ

This is the LINQ that I have:

```cs
List<FromTextFile> sortedList = ColumnsSwapped
    .OrderBy(o => o.Column1)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Column2)
    .ToList();
```

This is the result that I am getting:

```
    Column1; Column2
    QA7878729D; D9278787AQ
    QA7878736A; A6378787AQ
    QA7878751B; B1578787AQ
    QA7878834C; C4388787AQ
    QB7878726D; D6278787BQ
```

This is the result that I want:

```
    Column1; Column2
    QA7878736A; A6378787AQ
    QA7878751B; B1578787AQ
    QA7878834C; C4388787AQ
    QA7878729D; D9278787AQ
    QB7878726D; D6278787BQ
```

Is there something wrong with my LINQ? Am I not using `.ThenBy()` correctly?

I want to order `Column1` `QA > QB` and for `Column2` after ordering the `Column1`, it sorts from `A > B`.

```
    QA-A
    QA-B
    QA-C
    QA-D
    QB-D
```

Comment: Would be great if you can specify your ordering rule. Order by `Column2` first? But why "D6278787BQ" is after "D9278787AQ"? If you order by `Column1`, why "QA7878729D" should be 4th instead of 1st?

Comment: @YongShun I want to order Column1 QA > QB and for Column2 after ordering the Column1, it sorts from A > B.

Answer (score 1):

From your expected result, you should order by:

1. First 2 characters from `Column1` to achieve QA > QB
2. First character from `Column2` to achieve A > B

(Optional) If you want to further ordering for `Column1` and `Column2` by sequence:

3. `Column1`
4. `Column2`

```cs
List<FromTextFile> SortedList = ColumnsSwapped
    .OrderBy(o => o.Column1.Substring(0, 2))
    .ThenBy(o => o.Column2.Substring(0, 1))
    .ThenBy(o => o.Column1)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Column2)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Z6Yni)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only want to sort by the first 2 characters in `Column1` and the first character in `Column2`. If that's the case, you only need to change your Linq to:

```
List<FromTextFile> SortedList = ColumnsSwapped.OrderBy(o => o.Column1.Substring(0, 2)).ThenBy(o => o.Column2.Substring(0, 1)).ToList();
```

That should ignore the last characters, which means you get 'duplicates' for `Column1`, which will cause the `ThenBy` to order by the first character in `Column2`.

**Alternative syntax** (does exactly the same):

```
List<FromTextFile> SortedList = ColumnsSwapped.OrderBy(o => o.Column1[..2]).ThenBy(o => o.Column2[0]).ToList();
```